# How to go to the line which caused the error in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, runtime-error

I am using `xcode 10 beta` i am getting common errors that occur during the unavailability of data or unwrapping optionals, but how can i go to that line that caused the error or which array in out of index or which optional is being unwrapped?

Here is what i get

[image]

How to reach the line or optional or array that caused the error?

**Update** : after placing exception breakpoint

[image]

Comment: try with Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: Try to understand crash log which print without breakpoint or put Exception breakpoint and run app when app crash it will redirect to that line.

Comment: @HardikThakkar i placed the line but it does not redirect on the line of code but green the same line which is red in in the image i posted

Comment: In your case you need to findout some way to solve error, crash is sure related to value find as nil. we can't find any solution from this screenshot.

Comment: @HardikThakkar would you mention what ways should i follow

Comment: sorry bro, without proper information i can't get idea of real error, but try to comment one by one actions you perform and findout exact location, and what is ViewController.reportTable i see that line in screenshot.

Comment: problem found it was a nill in a field

Comment: @HardikThakkar thanx for time

Answer (score 1):

Try this following way:

[image]

**Select second option. Exception Breakpoint...**

Comment: i placed the line but it does not redirect on the line of code but green the same line which is red in in the image i posted